# How do I purge messages from a single user on discord.net and c#?

Tags: c#, discord, purge, discord.net

I've made a purge command for my discord bot, it works fine...

(simple version)

```
int amount = Int32.Parse(e.GetArg("amount"))+1;
Message[] messagesToDelete = await e.Channel.DownloadMessages(amount);
await e.Channel.DeleteMessages(messagesToDelete);
```

Now I want to do the same, but only deleting messages from a single user, but I can't seem to get it working... This is what I have right now:

```
int amount = Int32.Parse(e.GetArg("amount"));
ulong userID = e.Server.FindUsers(e.GetArg("user")).First().Id;

Message[] messagesToDelete = await e.Channel.DownloadMessages(amount, userID);
await e.Channel.DeleteMessages(messagesToDelete);
```

This second code seems to only delete the command and nothing else... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
using System.Linq;

var users = e.Server.FindUsers(e.GetArg("user")).ToArray();
var msgs = (await e.Channel.DownloadMessages(amount));
msgs = msgs.Where(x => users.Contains(x.User));
```

Then loop through `msgs` and call delete on each one.

This separates out the messages to only include the ones we're interested in (i.e. the messages by the specified user).

Of course you're going to want some safety checks too such as checking if `e.GetArg("user")` is empty, if it's actually a user, checking if `msgs` contains any messages, if `e.Channel.Messages` is less than your `amount`, etc. Untested but this should get you in the right direction.

Comment: That wouldn't work, if my command said 5 messages, it'd download the 5 latest messages, and within those 5 delete all the messages from that user.

For Example, imagine that the user in question said the same thing 6 times in a row, and I want to delete the last 5 of them, however, people have sent 3 more messages after that. if my command had the code you sent, and I typed it with 5 for the amount as it should be, it'd only delete the last 2 messages.